# Need to control order of method expectation based on the expectation of a property being set

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have the following example that does not behave in the way I would expect.

```
public abstract class Example
{
    public abstract string Foo();

    public List<string> Bar()
    {
        PreMethod();

        var list = new List<string>();

        var stack = new Stack<string>();
        foreach (var item in Stuff)
        {
            stack.Push(item);
        }

        while (stack.Any())
        {
            SomeThing = stack.Pop();
            var f = Foo();
            list.Add(f);
        }

        PostMethod();
        return list;
    }

    public abstract void PreMethod();

    public abstract void PostMethod();

    public abstract IEnumerable<string> Stuff { get; }

    public abstract string SomeThing { set; get; }
}

[TestClass]
public class ExampleTest
{
    private Example example;

    private MockRepository mocks;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitializeTest()
    {
        mocks = new MockRepository();
        example = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<Example>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void BarTest()
    {
        using (mocks.Ordered())
        {
            example.Expect(e => e.PreMethod());
            example.Expect(e => e.Stuff).Return(new[] { "One", "Two" });

            using (mocks.Unordered())
            {
                using (mocks.Ordered())
                {
                    example.Expect(e => e.SomeThing).SetPropertyWithArgument("One");
                    example.Expect(e => e.Foo()).Return("one");
                }

                using (mocks.Ordered())
                {
                    example.Expect(e => e.SomeThing).SetPropertyWithArgument("Two");
                    example.Expect(e => e.Foo()).Return("two");
                }
            }


            example.Expect(e => e.PostMethod());
        }

        mocks.ReplayAll();


        var actual = example.Bar();
        Assert.AreEqual(2, actual.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("two", actual[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual("one", actual[1]);
    }
}
```

So, the expectation is that by putting the calls to `Something` and `Foo` inside of `using(mocks.Ordered)` that `Foo` will return the value based on what `Something` was just set to, but the test fails because the resulting list actually has "one", then "two".  When I debug I see that after `Something` is set to "Two" the call to `Foo` returns "one".  Basically I just want to make the return of `Foo` to be connected to what `Something` was set to, but without knowing the order that they will be set (basically this test shouldn't be effected by changing the code to use a Queue instead of a Stack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first thing I found out is that ordering does not work with the AAA style.  Second I discovered that I can achieve what I'm looking for by using `WhenCalled`.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void BarTest()
    {
        example.Expect(e => e.PreMethod());
        example.Expect(e => e.Stuff).Return(new[] { "One", "Two" });
        example.Expect(e => e.SomeThing)
            .SetPropertyWithArgument("One")
            .WhenCalled(obj => example.Expect(e => e.Foo()).Return("one"));
        example.Expect(e => e.SomeThing)
            .SetPropertyWithArgument("Two")
            .WhenCalled(obj => example.Expect(e => e.Foo()).Return("two"));
        example.Expect(e => e.PostMethod());

        var actual = example.Bar();

        Assert.AreEqual(2, actual.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual("two", actual[0]);
        Assert.AreEqual("one", actual[1]);
        example.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }
```

By putting the expectations inside of the `WhenCalled` it ensures that the expectations happen in the expected order.